# Why data is not displayed on my asp.net webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datalist

I am developing Canteen Management System where I am displaying `menuList` from Database using `gridview` like given below.. ( this is `Menu.aspx` page)

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="nav-justified" style="height: 111px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("menuName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="viewDetail" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("menuImage") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("menuPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Cms_AspFormsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [menuName], [menuPrice], [menuImage], [Id] FROM [menuInfo]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is `Menu.aspx.cs` page

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.CommandName == "viewDetail" )
    {
        Response.Redirect("MenuDetails.aspx?Id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}
```

but When i run this this it's showing nothing, ( when i go to source page it was all empty at like given below..)

```
<div>
        
        <br />
   
</div>
```

Why it' showing empty? and how to resolve this?

Comment: Well, in your event code, does a debug.print e.commandArugment show any value before you jump to the other page? and if you type in the id by hand into the url, does the other page work??

Answer (score 0):

Add DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" to the DataList tag. Data source was not set for the control.